# SQLite EXP function

Tags: database, sqlite

I was wondering if there is a way to have the EXP function in SQLite. I am accessing a SQLite database and I need to recreate a Logistic Regression estimator by means of SQL code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *core* SQLite, you cannot, but it does have the ability to create [User Defined Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html), so you could write your own.

Luckily, someone has already done this... the last entry (at time of writing) of this [Contributed Files](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib) page from the SQLite website is a link to `extension-functions.c` which claims<sup>**1**</sup> to implement many mathematical functions, including `exp()`.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> As per the disclaimer at the top of that page, "*The content of these files has not been verified. Use at your own risk.*". However, the SQLite mailing list frequently recommends this plugin so I think you're probably safe.

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite you have just this core functions:

[SQLite Core functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

The only numeric/math functions are the following:

```
abs, avg, count, max, min, random, round, sum
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)